# Programmatically assign GetPivotData formula to a cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Run-time error '1004':

Application-defined or Object-defined error

I want set a cell formula with the code below:

```
Selection.Formula = "=GETPIVOTDATA(""Value"";$M$26;""M"";1;""Y"";1396)"
```

Above formula works in the sheet correctly as bellow:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Value";$M$26;"M";1;"Y";1396)
```

but when I try to assign to appropriate cell with macro, above error shown.

How can I assign this formula to cells, by VBA macro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VBA normal format is American English.

so either:

Change the `;` to `,`:

```
Selection.Formula = "=GETPIVOTDATA(""Value"",$M$26,""M"",1,""Y"",1396)"
```

Or use `.FormulaLocal`:

```
Selection.FormulaLocal = "=GETPIVOTDATA(""Value"";$M$26;""M"";1;""Y"";1396)"
```